# Trying to convert to numbers with try except

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, type-conversion, try-except

I'm trying to convert the items in a list of multiple types to floats, so that

```
L = ["29.3", "tea", "1", None, 3.14]
```

would become

```
D = [29.3, "tea", 1, None, 3.14]
```

My attempt is as follows:

```
L = ["29.3", "tea", "1", None, 3.14]
D = []
for item in L:
    try:
        float(item)
        D.append(item)
    except ValueError:
        D.append(item)

print(D)
```

This throws up a

> ```
> line 5, in <module>
>     float(item)
> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'` error.
> ```

If I change the `None` item to a string as in `"None"`, it generates a list `D` identical to `L`. So...

1. How do I skip over the `None` item? Do I have to use an `if item == None: pass` statement, or is there a better way?
2. Why is the type conversion not working even if I change `None` to `"None"`?

Comment: What do you want to convert `None` to?

Comment: `float(item)` doesn't achieve anything because it is not reassign `item`. Use `item = float(item)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`try-except` is for catching exceptions. In this scenario, you only account for one exception, `ValueError` but not `TypeError`. In order to catch type error, just put one more `except` block below `try`. In your case, it would be like this:

```
L = ["29.3", "tea", "1", None, 3.14]
D = []
for item in L:
    try:
        float(item)
        D.append(float(item))
    except TypeError:
        # do something with None here
    except ValueError:
        D.append(item)

print(D)
```

Given that you want to catch multiple exceptions in a single `except` block, use a tuple of exceptions:

```
L = ["29.3", "tea", "1", None, 3.14]
D = []
for item in L:
    try:
        float(item)
        D.append(float(item))
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        D.append(item)
print(D)
```

Comment: Regarding your last update, I edited it. You *should not* catch any exception except in some specific cases such as logging errors before *reraising*. The reason for that is that if an exception you did not expect was raised, then you definitely do not want it to pass silently as it is a *bug*.  Errors should never pass silently.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly do the append in the `try` block:

#### Code:

```
try:
    D.append(float(item))
except (ValueError, TypeError):
    D.append(item)
```

#### Test Code:

```
L = ["29.3", "tea", "1", None, 3.14]
D = []
for item in L:
    try:
        D.append(float(item))
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        D.append(item)

print(D)
```

#### Results:

```
[29.3, 'tea', 1.0, None, 3.14]
```

Answer (score 2):

When the `float` constructor is given something else than a string or a number, it raises a `TypeError` instead of a `ValueError`. You need to catch both.

Here is a way using list-comprehension.

```
def try_float(x):
    try:
        return float(x)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return x

l = ["29.3", "tea", "1", None, 3.14]
d = [try_float(x) for x in l]

print(d)  # [29.3, 'tea', 1.0, None, 3.14]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes， you can simply use `if item == None: pass` to check the type before converting.
2. You can use `if isinstance(item, str): ...` to explicitly converte the string to float.

Answer (score 0):

Try cincudate the errors, using them in the last case. So if the error is in NoneType, you can try circundate with `if var is type:` or `if is isinstance(var, type):`
In other types like bool (True/False) you shoud use the eval(var) to transform them to bool.

```
L = ["29.3", "tea", "1", None, 3.14]
D = []

for item in L:
    if item is None:
        D.append(item)
        pass
    else:
        try:
            D.append(float(item))
        except ValueError or TypeError:
            D.append(item)
```